# How can I setup CodePipeline and CodeCommit in different regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment

I have my code (CodeCommit) in Ireland and my ECS cluster in London. I want to setup a CodePipeline, so when commit new changes they are deployed to ECS cluster.

Currently, I'm not able to do that because the services are in different regions. I've read some solutions like replicate CodeCommit repo in the other region periodically or using Lambdas or whatever, but I found it an ugly solution.

Is there another elegant way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline recently released support for cross-region actions: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-codepipeline-now-supports-cross-region-actions/

This would allow you to run eg. CodeCommit and your pipeline in Ireland, and deploy to an ECS cluster in London.